# The tour page is now a generic stackexchange version

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the sandbox phase, the tour page (here: https://mathoverflow.net/about) was populated with MO-specific questions/answers. Now it has generic (and to my mind, overly silly) questions, and I would like the old one back, please.

Comment: Should have happened automatically; might still happen automatically, but I'll poke at it a bit.

Comment: Now when you say generic... over what universe? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a moderator, I see edit links around various bits of the tour. It looks like mods will have the option of replacing the unicorns with whatever MO question we like, but for now it says "There are currently no viable question candidates for the About page" when I try to edit it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164516/please-ping-moderators-whenever-the-sites-about-page-gets-modified

Comment: Try it again now. I see lots of options to choose from. Probably just a process that needed to catch up after the migration.

Comment: Lots of tasty questions to select from now.

Comment: Thanks, Anton. I'll accept your answer.